# How to ensure that the same comment appears for each struct in a namespace using doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have the following namespace and some code in a file called `impstrcts.h`

```
namespace mynameSpace{

/*!
some doxygen for the collection of label_str, Label_map, big_map
*/

/*!
some doxygen for the label_str
*/
template<template<typename ...> class Tcont, typename... Titem>
struct label_str
{
    Tcont<Titem...> kindA;
};

/*!
* some doxygen commnets for label_map
*/
struct Label_map
{
    label_str<std::map, alpha, beta> al_beta_map;
};

/*!
* some doxygen comments for big_map
*/
struct big_map
{
    Label_map first;
    Label_map second;
};
}
```

Is there a way I can have the general doxygen comment appear by itself or maybe with every struct in the namespace? Because right now, the `some doxygen for the collection of label_str, Label_map, big_map` appears only for the `label_str` struct.

Comment: Can't you just document the namespace?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What settings do you use other than the default doxygen settings (so the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`), please edit this info into the question. What do you see and what are you missing (images in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default doxygen configuration file, you can put the common documentation onto some "object" such as a group and use `\copydoc` to copy it. For example:

```
namespace mynameSpace{

/*!
\defgroup MyCollection
some doxygen for the collection of label_str, Label_map, big_map
*/

/*!
\brief some doxygen for the label_str
\copydoc MyCollection
*/
template<template<typename ...> class Tcont, typename... Titem>
struct label_str
{
    Tcont<Titem...> kindA;
};

/*!
* \brief some doxygen commnets for label_map
* \copydoc MyCollection
*/
struct Label_map
{
    label_str<std::map, alpha, beta> al_beta_map;
};

/*!
* \brief some doxygen comments for big_map
* \copydoc MyCollection
*/
struct big_map
{
    Label_map first;
    Label_map second;
};
}
```

The explicit `\brief` statements were necessary in my tests to ensure that doxygen does not confuse brief with details.

Instead of defining a custom group, you could also simply put the documentation at the namespace `mynameSpace` and use `\copydoc mynameSpace`:

```
/// some doxygen for the collection of label_str, Label_map, big_map
namespace mynameSpace{

/*!
\brief some doxygen for the label_str
\copydoc mynameSpace
*/
template<template<typename ...> class Tcont, typename... Titem>
struct label_str
{
    Tcont<Titem...> kindA;
};

/*!
* \brief some doxygen commnets for label_map
* \copydoc mynameSpace
*/
struct Label_map
{
    label_str<std::map, alpha, beta> al_beta_map;
};

/*!
* \brief some doxygen comments for big_map
* \copydoc mynameSpace
*/
struct big_map
{
    Label_map first;
    Label_map second;
};
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get the effect of `\copydoc` somehow automatically. There is something called ["member groups"](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) and the configuration variable `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` which can be set to `YES` (default is `NO`). They do something that is related to what you want: Every member of a group gets the description of the first member. However, it apparently does not work for structs/classes. And in any case, the members must not be documented otherwise (no automatic merging of documentation even if it were to work for structs/classes).